# Pandas Generating dataframe based on columns being present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Players': [ 'Sam', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Sam',
                 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Greg', 'Steve'],
                 'Wins': [10,5,5,20,30,20,6,9,3,10],
                 'Losses': [5,5,5,2,3,2,16,20,3,12],
                 'Type': ['A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','B'],
                 })
```

If I wanted to summarize the I can manually make another dataframe:

```
p=df.groupby('Players')

summary = pd.DataFrame({'Total Games': p.Players.count(),
                        'Average Wins':p.Wins.mean(),
                        'Greatest Wins':p.Wins.max(),
                        'Unique games':p.Type.nunique()})
```

Lets say I want to automate this summarizing process to create a dataframe if column X is present perform summarization Y what would the best way of doing this? I have attempted using a dictionary but I think I did something wrong

```
p=df.groupby('Players')
sumdict = {'Total Games': ['Players', p.Players.count()],
            'Average Wins':['Wins', p.Wins.mean()],
            'Greatest Wins':['Wins', p.Wins.max()],
            'Unique games':['Type', p.Type.nunique()],
            'Max Score':['Score', p.Score.max()]}

summary=pd.DataFrame()

for key, value in sumdict.items():
        if value[0] in df.columns:
            data = pd.DataFrame({key: value[1],})
            summary=summary.append(data)
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Your last snippet doesn't run as there is no `Score` column

Comment: @EdChum I am aware of that the `continue` was suppose to skip it if it was not present.

Comment: But your dict can't be created as it's trying to store a reference to the max of that column

Comment: @EdChum I can't think of any other way to do it other than using a bunch of `try` and `except` loops

Comment: Why don't you declare a list of columns and build the dict based on the presence of the columns in your df, at the moment you can't define a dict by trying to take a reference to a column that doesn't exist

Comment: @EdChum That will not work because if I use the columns for dict keys I cannot have `Wins` as a key twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `DataFrame`s support most of the `dict` methods, include `get` (which allows you to substitute a value for an empty key).  So you can do the statistics you want on all columns, then get the values for the column you want, substituting an empty `Series` for missing columns, then drop `NaN` columns (I use `Bad Value` to demonstrate what happens to missing columns):

```
eser = pd.Series()
count = p.count().max(axis=1)
all_max = p.max()
score_max = all_max.get('Score', eser)
wins_max = all_max.get('Wins', eser)
wins_mean = p.mean().get('Wins', eser)
type_nunique = p.agg(lambda x: x.nunique()).get('Type', eser)

summary = pd.DataFrame({'Total Games': count,
                        'Average Wins': wins_mean,
                        'Greatest Wins': wins_max,
                        'Unique games': type_nunique,
                        'Max Score': score_max})
summary.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Or a one-liner (which involves calculating the `max` on all columns twice, which shouldn't be a problem for a small number of values):

```
summary = pd.DataFrame({'Total Games': p.count().max(axis=1),
                        'Average Wins': p.mean().get('Wins', pd.Series()),
                        'Greatest Wins': p.max().get('Wins', pd.Series()),
                        'Unique games': p.agg(lambda x: x.nunique()).get('Type', pd.Series()),
                        'Max Score': p.max().get('Score', pd.Series())}).dropna(axis=1, how='all')
```

The result of either approach:

```
       Average Wins  Greatest Wins  Total Games  Unique games
Greg             11             30            4             2
Sam              15             20            2             2
Steve            11             20            4             2
```

Without the `dropna`:

```
       Average Wins  Greatest Wins  Max Score  Total Games  Unique games
Greg             11             30        NaN            4             2
Sam              15             20        NaN            2             2
Steve            11             20        NaN            4             2
```

If performance is an issue, the above will be slow because they require computing multiple statistics on all columns, which means statistics are being computed and then thrown away.  A faster, but uglier, approach is similar to your approach of using a loop over a `dict`.

The problem with your implementation is that the `dict` items are **not** lazily evaluated, they are evaluated when the `dict` is created, which means it still tries to access the non-existent columns.

The approach below gets both the item and applies the function only when the column is found (with special handling for the `count` case, since any existing column will work):

```
sumdict = {'Total Games': (None, 'count'),
           'Average Wins': ('Wins', 'mean'),
           'Greatest Wins': ('Wins', 'max'),
           'Unique games': ('Type', 'nunique'),
           'Max Score': ('Score', 'max')}

summary = []
for key, (column, op) in sumdict.items():
    if column is None:
        res = p.agg(op).max(axis=1)
    elif column not in df:
        continue
    else: 
        res = p[column].agg(lambda x: getattr(x, op)())
    summary.append(pd.DataFrame({key: res}))
summary = pd.concat(summary, axis=1)
```

It gives the same result as my above approaches, although with a different column order.

Comment: would you suggest the first solution for a large dataset?

Comment: Probably not.  Your `dict` based approach will be faster in such a situation.  This involved calculating all statistics for all columns, but throw away all but one or two.  If this is a significant performance bottleneck for you, then you should use another approach.  I will edit my answer to include a faster, but uglier, version.

Comment: Wow this works for all cases unless I use `apply` and a lambda function