# Summarizing Dataframes with ambiguous columns with apply function

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a dataframe and a for loop with dictionary to define how to handle specific column names from my previous question: [Pandas Generating dataframe based on columns being present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964552/pandas-generating-dataframe-based-on-columns-being-present)

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Players': [ 'Sam', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Sam',
                 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Greg', 'Steve'],
                 'Wins': [10,5,5,20,30,20,6,9,3,10],
                 'Losses': [5,5,5,2,3,2,16,20,3,12],
                 'Type': ['A','B','B','B','A','B','B','A','A','B'],
                 })

p=df.groupby('Players')



sumdict = {'Total Games': (None, 'count'),
           'Average Wins': ('Wins', 'mean'),
           'Greatest Wins': ('Wins', 'max'),
           'Unique games': ('Type', 'nunique'),
           'Max Score': ('Score', 'max')}

summary = []
for key, (column, op) in sumdict.items():
    if column is None:
        res = p.agg(op).max(axis=1)
    elif column not in df:
        continue
    else:
        res = p[column].agg(lambda x: getattr(x, op)())
    summary.append(pd.DataFrame({key: res}))
summary = pd.concat(summary, axis=1)
```

The code works for almost all cases except for `apply` functions that count specific cases inside a column:

```
streak = pd.DataFrame({'Streak':p.Wins.apply(lambda x: (x > 5).sum())})
```

Is there a way to incorporate the apply function into the dictionary `sumdict`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1. check for a function and use that rather the getattr.
2. just use the string and let the function fall through...

IMO 2. is a little cleaner (although perhaps lesser known?) that you can do `g.agg("max")` as an alias to `g.max()`.

```
sumdict["Streak"] = "Wins", lambda x: (x > 5).sum()
```

and you do the following, the commented line is the only change:

```
summary = []
for key, (column, op) in sumdict.items():
    if column is None:
        res = p.agg(op).max(axis=1)
    elif column not in df:
        continue
    else:
        res = p[column].agg(op)  # just use the string (or it could be a func)
    summary.append(pd.DataFrame({key: res}))
summary = pd.concat(summary, axis=1)
```

Then Streak works just perfect:

```
In [23]: summary
Out[23]:
         Greatest Wins  Total Games  Streak  Average Wins  Unique games
Players
Greg                30            4       2            11             2
Sam                 20            2       2            15             2
Steve               20            4       3            11             2
```